# Why is my `Label` renderer font style not being applied to Label's Text in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I created a `Label` renderer that uses the `UIFontTextStyle.Body` font style.

```
public class LabelBodyCustomRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
            Control.Font = UIFont.GetPreferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyle.Body);
    }
}
```

I then use it in  `XAML` like below:

`<local:LabelBodyRendererClass x:Name="numberAnswerLabel" />`

And populate the `Label`'s text in `C#`:

`numberAnswerLabel.Text = App.noa.Text() + " correct";`

Doing it this way, the `UIFontTextStyle.Body` is not applied to the label but if I populate the `Label`'s text in the `XAML` side like:

`<local:LabelBodyRendererClass Text="sample text" />`

then font style is applied.

Anyone has any idea why is it working like this? And how to fix it so it will use the style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the font is reset whenever the text or any associated property of the font is changed.

So you would have to handle the `TextChanged` event and then reapply the font. Have a look at my code for this in the [FormsCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/FormsCommunityToolkit/FormsCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/src/Effects/Effects.iOS/Effects/Label/LabelCustomFont.cs#L25).

Whenever one of these properties change, I apply the new font again:

```
if (e.PropertyName == Label.TextColorProperty.PropertyName
                    || e.PropertyName == Label.FontProperty.PropertyName
                    || e.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName
                    || e.PropertyName == Label.FormattedTextProperty.PropertyName)
{
    control.Font = UIFont.FromName (_effect.FontFamilyName, control.Font.PointSize);
}
```

It has something to do with the 'bug' reported [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33666).